# Thymeleaf incorrectly loads static files

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

So I had static css files loading correctly and then for whatever reason, can't tell why, they stopped loading right.
Here is my project structure:

[image]

import in index.html:

```
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" th:href="@{/css/styles.css}"/>
</head>
```

I even tried to set `spring.resources.static-locations=classpath:/static/` in `application.properties` to no avail.

And the best part:
[image]
when inspecting website - `styles.css` is loaded as `index.html` in `templates` folder.

what do?

Answer (score 2):

In spring security 4.x - the resources are `permitAll` in spring security.

In spring security 5.x - you should manually config it.

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/css/**", "/js/**").permitAll()
}
```

Comment: i don't have spring boot security starter at all, however it didn't help anyway, still loads styles.css as index.html...

Answer (score 0):

Please try to check below points:
1. ResourceHandler has css location

```
class WebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {
  @Override
  public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addResourceHandler("/css/**")
      .addResourceLocations("classpath:/static/css/");
  }

  ...
}
```

2. Exclude *.css in spring-security rules

```
class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

  @Override
  public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
    web.ignoring().antMatchers(
      "/css/\**",
      "/js/\**",
      "/img/\**",
      ...
    );
  }

  ...
}
```